# htaccess for mutliple domains on a single webhost

Tags: .htaccess

If I have a website with the domain someone.com which is the main site and two other domains mything.com and yourthing.com. All domains point to the same IP and the same path on the server.

When i go to someone.com, index.php is loaded and but when I visit mything.com and yourthing.com i want index.php loaded with a parameter like:
index.php?site=mything.com
In the code i'll identify which domain it is and load the relevant data.

In the address bar at the client I want the entered domain name to remain.

How can I achieve this with htaccess?

Cheers...

Comment: Are all pages sent to index.php? If not, would you want the site variable appended to all pages, i.e. about.php?site=mything.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, using the $_SERVER vars and some nifty apache setup.